# Which data from Telephony.Mms.Part indicates a reaction?

Tags: android, telephony, mms, android-mms, rich-communications-services

Querying the MMS parts database on Android will give MMS message bodies like '❤️ to "hello"' for reactions.

How can one know if these are true reactions or if someone typed that out?

Looked at various columns in the MMS parts table. One clue is that the type will be smil for reactions that are animated.

Comment: Hi. This isn't related to RCS (revision control system) so please remove the tag. Thanks.

Comment: Updated to rich-communications-services. Thank you!